# How do you make an image follow your mouse pointer using jQUERY?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have looked up and there are a few threads similar to this but I cant make any of them work for me so I have to ask my code at the moment is.It is different

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylespacewars.css" />
        <script src="jsspacewars.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery.js"></script>
        <img class="Ship" src="Ally ship.gif" alt="HTML5 Icon" >
        <img class="EnemieBasic" src="Basic enemie.gif" alt="HTML5 Icon" >
        <img class="Core" src="Corelevel1.gif" alt="HTML5 Icon" >
        <img class="Shot" src="Shot.gif" alt="HTML5 Icon" >
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

Then i have another part of the code in css

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black; }

IMG.Core {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto }

IMG.Ship {
    position:absolute;}
```

Then the final part is in Javascript

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
    $("Ship").css({left:e.pageX, top:e.pageY});
});
```

This does not allow the image ship to follow the mouse pointer can anyone help correct this please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Set the `position` of image to `absolute`
- Get **X** and **Y** coordinates of mouse
- Apply the **X** coordinate as `left` and **Y** coordinate as `top` to image

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).mousemove(function(e){
    $('img').css('left',e.pageX+"px");
    $('img').css('top',e.pageY+"px");
  });
});
```

```css
img {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://herbadmother.com/wp-content/themes/thesis_18/custom/rotator/sample-1.jpg" alt="" />
```

Comment: I've used your code and it work but the image is always a certain distance away anyone have any suggestions.

Comment: Use the CSS I've provided

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML and JS is a bit off. `img` tags go in the `body`. And for the jQuery you need to use `.` when referencing by class name.

http://jsfiddle.net/imthenachoman/1h3vsa3w/1/

The HTML:

```
<body>
    <img class="Ship" src="Ally ship.gif" alt="HTML5 Icon" />
    <img class="EnemieBasic" src="Basic enemie.gif" alt="HTML5 Icon" />
    <img class="Core" src="Corelevel1.gif" alt="HTML5 Icon" />
    <img class="Shot" src="Shot.gif" alt="HTML5 Icon" />
</body>
```

The JavaScript:

```
$(document).mousemove(function (e)
{
    $(".Ship").css({ left: e.pageX, top: e.pageY });
});
```

Comment: Please include relevant code in answer itself. Otherwise, good answer! BTW, seems better to hide img when mouse leaves the document: http://jsfiddle.net/1h3vsa3w/2/

Answer (score 1):

What you are building is simple, so please learn to do it with plain JavaScript first. If anything is not working you can find out exactly why.

There are three aspects of making an image follow the mouse cursor. 1. is the onmousemove event firing properly? 2. are you getting the right coordinates? 3. is the position update effective?

Let's look at each point.

1. To track the mouse movement, the following is sufficient:

   document.onmousemove=function(e){

   }
2. Depends on the browser, the "e" parameter may not be passed in.

   document.onmousemove=function(e){
     var x, y;
     if (e) {x=e.clientX; y=e.clientY;} 
     else {x=event.clientX;y=event.clientY;}

   }
3. Position the ship. Give the image an ID:

Try the following lines to see that you can indeed move it around:

```
var ship=document.getElementById('ship');
ship.style.top='200px';
ship.style.left='100px';
```

If the above code works, you can combine this with the previous snippet:

```
document.onmousemove=function(e){
  var x, y;
  if (e) {x=e.clientX; y=e.clientY;} 
  else {x=event.clientX;y=event.clientY;}

var ship=document.getElementById('ship');
ship.style.top=y+'px';
ship.style.left=x+'px';

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong selector with jQuery(`ship` must be a class or id of your image)

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
    $("#ship").css({left:e.pageX, top:e.pageY});
});
```

Here's a working [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/CkmlXGhNN50arL0jhbEL?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/JPvya/1275/

You weren't targeting the class by using the `.selector` method. Furthermore, you had the `img` in the `head` of your document. It needed to be part of the `body`.

Answer (score 0):

A period "." is required in your Javascript (since you are referencing a class)

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
    $(".Ship").css({left:e.pageX, top:e.pageY});
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tf9qebnv/1/